# Plotting graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to Python am trying to plot a graph based on the pyODE tutorial found [here](http://pyode.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial1.html). I'm using `pylab` for the plotting.
Below is the main part of the code and `#added` represents the code I've added in order to try and display the graph. When looking at the values themselves, `y` and `v` are the ones that change and `x,z,u,w` remain `0.000`. When I run the program, the axis scale keeps scaling, implying that something is happening regarding the values, but no line is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
yplot = 0 #added

#do the simulation
total_time = 0.0
dt = 0.04
while total_time<2.0:
    x,y,z = body.getPosition()
    u,v,w = body.getLinearVel()
    print "%1.2fsec: pos=(%6.3f,%6.3f,%6.3f) vel=(%6.3f,%6.3f,%6.3f)" % \
        (total_time, x,y,z,u,v,w)
    world.step(dt)
    total_time += dt    
    yplot += y #added
    plot(total_time, yplot) #added


xlabel('Time') #added
ylabel('Height') #added
show() #added
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to accumulate all the values you want to plot first, and then just call `plot` once.

```
yplot = 0 #added

#do the simulation
total_time = 0.0
dt = 0.04
times=[]
yvals=[]
while total_time<2.0:
    x,y,z = body.getPosition()
    u,v,w = body.getLinearVel()
    print "%1.2fsec: pos=(%6.3f,%6.3f,%6.3f) vel=(%6.3f,%6.3f,%6.3f)" % \
        (total_time, x,y,z,u,v,w)
    world.step(dt)
    total_time += dt
    yplot += y 
    times.append(total_time)
    yvals.append(yplot)
plot(times, yvals,'r-')
xlabel('Time') #added
ylabel('Height') #added
show() #added
```

The third argument to plot, `'r-'`, tells `pylab` to draw a red line connecting the points listed in `times`,`yvals`. When you plot points one-at-a-time, there is no way to tell `pylab` to connect the dots because each plot contains only a single point. Calling `plot` for each point is also highly inefficient.