# Python Graph that shows relationship between three variables

Tags: python, math, graph, relationship

I have a Python Function that has the arguments `Slope` and `Distance` and it returns `Cost`.
Slope can be in the range 1 - 80.
Distance can be in the range 1 - 20000.
Cost can be any positive number.

I want to see the relationship between slope, distance, and cost.
What would be the best plot to show the relationship between these three variables? And how would I create it. 
I want to know for instance what happens to cost if slope goes up and distance down?
What happens to cost if slope and distance go up?
etc...

```
def func(Slope, Distance):
     ...
     return cost


SlopeList = list(xrange(81))
DistanceList = list(xrange(20000)



myList= []
for Distance in DistanceList:
    for Slope in SlopeList:   
         cost = func(Slope, Distance)
         var = (Slope, Distance, Cost)
         append.myList(var)
```

Comment: I recommend that you use [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Home). It is a virtually unknown library that specializes in these sort of things. **NOTE:** Made only for Mac OSX.

Comment: So... Do you want a graph *based* on three variables (3D), or one that *uses* three variables? In the case of the later, this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4555948/1993598

Comment: The question is not only how to display it, but more how can I calculate the function so the results depend on all the variables and none of them is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear, so I'll try to cover all the possibilities:

a) If you have a function of two variables, like `func`, and you can execute that function for many combinations of the two variables, you can use `matplotlib` to draw a contour plot with (perhaps) Slope and Distance on the x and y axes respectively, and Cost shown as contours. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) for an example.

b) If you have a function such as:

```
Cost = func(Slope,Distance)
```

... and you know Cost and the value of one of the other two variables, then you could either:

b1) Write two more functions (e.g. `funcSlope(Cost,Distance)` and `funcDistance(Slope,Cost)`) that produce the unknown variable from the known variables, or

b2) If either the function `func` is unavailable to you, so you don't know how it is computed and therefore cannot explicitly write the functions that I've suggested for option 1, or it is hard to invert `func` analytically to find Slope or Distance from the other two variables, you can find the unknown variable numerically using code that is something like this:

```
def func(Slope,Distance):
    # Imagine that we didn't know the definition of this function
    # so we couldn't write funcSlope() explicitly
    return Slope * Distance**0.1234

def funcSlope(Cost,Distance,minSlope,maxSlope):
    def fs (Slope):
        return Cost - func(Slope,Distance)
    return scipy.optimize.brentq(fs, minSlope, maxSlope)

print (func(2,6))
print (funcSlope(2.4949,6,0,10))
```

... for which the output is:

```
2.494904118641096
1.999996698357211
```

You'll see that you need to specify bounds for the unknown variable when calling `brentq()`.

Comment: Thanks Simon for your detailed answer! I edited my post a little to clarify a little bit more what I am looking for. I think I am looking for a solution like you layed out in a). I will look into contour plot. Unfortunately I am not sure either what I exactly need in order to see the relationship between these three variables.